# Add new item to validatedObservable in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Lets say i have a validated observable and inside there is an extended observable.
This works fine.

```
  var validationModel = ko.validatedObservable([
    model.text1.extend({required: true})
  ]);
```

If i then add to this validatedObservable's array i would expect it to now be aware of the new validation, however this is not the case.

```
  validationModel().push(
    model.text2.extend({required: true})
  );
```

Is it possible to extend the validation to new observables without reinitialising the validationModel?

I attempted to use `model.text2.notifySubscribers()` and this sort of works as in the validation message is triggered. However `isValid()` is still showing as true.

Here's an working example that shows what i am talking about:

http://liveweave.com/MBq7XU

Answer (score 1):

I have been tinkering around looking in the source and the only way I can see is to pass in a new array. Given that I want the add to the old array this is the most elegant thing I can think off.

```
  validationModel(ko.utils.arrayPushAll(validationModel(),
    [model.text2.extend({required: true})]
  ));
```

http://liveweave.com/sUxgeO

---

#### Not working?

It turns out I am using an older version of validation (from nuget). This version implements the validatedObservable differently that was producing some side effects.

As such I ended up having to use this code instead to achieve what I needed.

```
kovalidation.pushValidation = function (validatedObservable, itemsArray)
{
   var newValidatables = ko.utils.arrayPushAll(validatedObservable(), itemsArray);
   validatedObservable(newValidatables);
   validatedObservable.errors = kovalidation.group(newValidatables);
};
```

which could be used like:

```
  kovalidation.pushValidation(validationModel,
    [model.text2.extend({required: true})]
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more extensive investigation, I don't believe my previous answer is entirely correct as it ignores the underlying subscription within `validatedObservable`.

As such I have come to the conclusion that it is best to build up an array and then only initialise `ko.validatedObservable([..wholearray..])` when you have everything.

If you really must add to a `validatedObservable` that already exists I think your only choice is to pull out the array and then reinitialise it.

```
var validationModel = ko.validatedObservable([...])
var underlyingArray = validationModel();
underlyingArray.concat([...]);
validationModel = new ko.observable(underlyingArray);
```